# How to set android ble receive notification interval

Tags: android, ios, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a hardware device, when it connected to IOS,  IOS receives 1 notification every 2 seconds. Then it connected to Android, Android receives 2 notifications every 4 seconds. So how to change Android receive notification interval?

Comment: Post your code plz.

Comment: use Android-nRF-Connect app